# Show number of assertions in RSpec output?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

By default, RSpec's output ends with something like

```
14 examples, 0 failures
```

Is it possible to show the number of assertions made along with this stat, similar to what other libraries provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no support for that. If you're interested in it, please feel free to submit a feature request at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good habit to have only one assertion per example spec.

Comment: but when doing integration tests with a sequence of steps, is there any way to avoid using multiple assertions (at least one per step)?